# iOS - Correct way to store user login session

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

What is the easiest correct way to store a session that tells whether or not a user is logged in? I could possibly even store basic information in memory (a logged-in user’s first and last name, etc.).

I’ve heard about singleton objects but I’m not sure if that is a solution or not. My main objective is to store basic user info for an application.

Could this work?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"someKeyName"]
```

I’m not sure if this is efficient, though, if I plan to use it for about 8 values.

Comment: Singleton should be fine.

Comment: Do you want the session to persist even when the app is terminated?

Comment: @BioCho Hi, yes I plan for the session to persist if the user gets out of the app, unless the user manually double taps the home button on the iphone and closes the app manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A singleton would be fine if you're not going to store any of the information in between sessions.

For example, if you wanted to save a user's email address so they don't have to fill it out every time to log in, you'll need to use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"someKeyName"];
```

Just like in your question.

Comment: OK great thanks for answer, I notice there is a valueForKey and setObject, is there a big difference here? Also is it OK to synchronize the NSUserDefaults after setting them, because I've run into problems where sometimes the value is stored but sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Firstly, yes you MUST synchronize after every time you set it, or you could see inconsistencies as you mentioned. Secondly, yes. valueForKey is for retrieving the value, while the setObject:forKey: is for setting. I personally try to use the custom setters and getters for each type, ex: "boolForKey" and "setBool:forKey" if I'm using boolean values. Check out the class reference for NSUserDefaults to see what's available (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Really appreciate the input. Thanks :)